# Simple Queue Implementation

Tags: java, queue

### Purpose

As I've never implemented a queue, I decided to create a very simple implementation using a linked list approach.

### Discussion

I create a singly linked list, using a `private` `Node` `class` that references some `data` and a `previous` `Node`,
that will be used in my `SimpleQueue` class.

When enqueuing data, I check to see if the linked list is empty or not (by checking to see if the `head` of the list is `null`).
If it's empty, point the `head` to a newly-created `Node` with the input data. If the list is not empty, I iterate through
the list until I reach the end (i.e. the `previous` `Node` is `null`) and then I insert a newly-created `Node`.

When dequeuing, I throw an `IllegalStateException` if the queue is empty. If the queue is not empty, I set the new head of
the queue to be the old head's `previous` value, and return the old head's `data` value.

### Implementation

```
public class SimpleQueue<T> {
    private Node<T> head;

    private class Node<E> {
        private final E data;
        private Node<E> previous;

        public Node(E data, Node<E> previous) {
            this.data = data;
            this.previous = previous;
        }
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return this.head == null;
    }

    public void enqueue(T data) {
        Node<T> currentNode = this.head;
        Node<T> nodeToInsert = new Node<>(data, null);

        if (this.isEmpty()) {
            this.head = nodeToInsert;
        } else {
            while (currentNode.previous != null) {
                currentNode = currentNode.previous;
            }

            currentNode.previous = nodeToInsert;
        }
    }

    public T dequeue() {
        if (this.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to dequeue from empty queue");
        }

        Node<T> currentNode = this.head;
        this.head = currentNode.previous;

        return currentNode.data;
    }

    public T peek() {
        if (this.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to peek empty queue");
        }

        return this.head.data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>             while (currentNode.previous != null) {
>                 currentNode = currentNode.previous;
>             }
>
>             currentNode.previous = nodeToInsert;
> ```

You can avoid this iteration if you track the location of the `tail` element.

```
            tail.previous = nodeToInsert;
            tail = tail.previous;
```

Of course, you have to maintain the `tail` in other places as well.

```
    private Node<T> tail;

    public void enqueue(T data) {
        Node<T> nodeToInsert = new Node<>(data, null);

        if (isEmpty()) {
            head = nodeToInsert;
        } else {
            tail.previous = nodeToInsert;
        }

        tail = nodeToInsert;
    }
```

But you no longer have to iterate this way.

Since both branches update `tail`, I moved that out of the `if`/`else`.

I notice that you use `this.` to specify object fields.  That actually isn't necessary unless there is a conflict with a parameter or local variable.  Of course, if you simply prefer it that way to make it obvious which variables are object fields, you can.

You can also update the `tail` when you `dequeue` to an empty queue, but you don't need to do so for functionality.  It does allow the garbage collector to collect the node though.

Answer (score 1):

#### Why "previous" ?

In common linked list implementations,
nodes are chained together from left to right,
and so the relation is usually labelled `next`.
`previous` is commonly used in doubly-linked lists.
Your implementation will be somewhat easier to read and look more natural to most programmers if you simply rename `previous` to `next`.

#### Borrow from the JDK

When trying to remove or get elements from an empty [`Queue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#remove()),
the JDK throws [`NoSuchElementException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html) instead of the more generic `IllegalStateException`.
When reinventing the wheel,
consider looking at the JDK as a reference to borrow ideas.
This will again make your code easier to read, and to use, if it's familiar.

#### Inner classes

The inner `Node` class doesn't need to reference anything in the enclosing class, so it can be a `static`.
Not only it's good to clarify this aspect,
it also improves performance by removing an unnecessary link.

#### Declare variables in the most limited scope

In `enqueue`, you declare `currentNode` up front,
but it's only used later in the `else` block of a condition.
Since it's not needed outside the condition,
it would be better to move this declaration inside the `else`.